# display custom post that has two taxonomies

Tags: php, html, wordpress

hey i'm trying to display posts that share term from two different taxonomies, but for some reason i just displays all posts. Not sure how to get this working. any help would be awesome! below is the arguments im using for my wp_query.

thanks in advance.

```
$args = array(
          'post_type' => $posttype,
                'posts_per_page' => 99999,
          'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'mytag',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => 'tag1',
              ),
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'mycategory',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => 'cat1',             
              ),
          ),
      );
```

html

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
<?php endif;?>
   html here...
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts found</h2>
<?php endif;
die();
```

Comment: @kip yes i am using it

Comment: try to change `'terms'    => 'cat1'` to an array value, `'terms'    => array('cat1')`, both terms and for `posts_per_page` use `-1` for no limit post for page

Comment: yea still just displays all posts

Answer (score 0):

// Correct code you closed endif before endwhile

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
    html here...
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>No posts found</h2>
<?php endif;
die();
```